# How to find which items uses a particular layout

Tags: sitecore

Is there a way in Sitecore to see if/which items uses a particular layout. I would like to change a layout but cannot find a way to see which items will be impacted by the change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could go to the layout item in Sitecore under for example '/sitecore/layout/Layouts/customername/page/standard layout'. Then you could open the references tab by opening the 'navigate' ribbon on top and selecting the arrow next to 'Links'. You will see a dropdown with the referers in it, which makes it easy to see what items depend on the layout.

Good luck!